# I can't get headers when I parse csv file with Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I can't get headers. No error happens. How can I get it properly?

Data:

```
"A","B","C"
"1","2","3"
```

Ruby:

```
require "csv"

table = CSV.read("filename", :headers => true)

puts table[0] # "1","2","3"

puts table[headers] # Nothing happens.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `table.headers`:

```
irb(main):006:0> table.headers
=> ["A", "B", "C"]
```

How are you running this code? `table[headers]` should return an error:

```
irb(main):008:0> table[headers]
NameError: undefined local variable or method `headers' for main:Object
    from (irb):8
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Thank you very much Blender! I could get headers. ; I didn't use irb. I did "ruby **.rb" on the terminal. In the case nothing happened.